# Update em um dialog fora da tab

Tags: javascript, jsf

Olá Pessoal estou tentando fazer um update para aparecer um dialog dlgPagamentos e não aparece ao clicar no botão pesquisar.

```
<p:dataTable id="tabelaPagamentos" var="pagamentoAux" widgetVar="tabelaPagamentosWdg"
            value="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.bean.pagamentos}"
            paginator="true" rows="5" style="width: auto; height: auto; margin:6px auto;"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

<p:column headerText="Código de Barras" style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;">
    <h:outputText value="#{pagamentoAux.codgBarraPagamento}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Autênticação" style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;">
    <h:outputText value="#{pagamentoAux.numrAutenticacaoBancaria}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Data Pagamento" style="text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;">
    <h:outputText value="#{pagamentoAux.dataPagamentoBanco}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" locale="pt_BR" timeZone="GMT-3" />
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>                        

<p:column headerText="Valor Pagamento" style="text-align: right; white-space: nowrap;" >
    <h:outputText value="#{pagamentoAux.valorRecebidoPagamento}" > 
        <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00" />
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>

<p:column  headerText="Agência Arrecadadora" style="text-align: left; width: 250px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{pagamentoAux.agenciaBancaria.nomeAgencia eq null ? pagamentoAux.codgAgenciaBancaria : pagamentoAux.agenciaBancaria.nomeAgencia }" />
</p:column>                                                            

</p:dataTable>


</p:dialog>  

<p:growl id="growlMessage" sticky="false" life="6000"
    globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" /> 

<!--Aba de Pesquisa de Pagamentos-->

<p:tab  title="Pesquisa de Pagamentos" id="tabPesquisaPagtos">
<!--                            <p:fieldset style="text-align: left" legend = "Dados do Pagamento">-->

<p:panel style="text-align: center; width: 40%">                                              
<div style="text-align: left">
    <p:panelGrid id="painelCamposPesquisaPag">                                                       
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="text-align: center">
                <h:outputText value="*Banco: " style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center" />        
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:autoComplete size="50" id="bancoAutoComplete" value="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.bean.banco}" completeMethod="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.pesquisaBanco}"
                                var="banco" itemLabel="#{banco.codigoBanco} - #{banco.nomeBanco}" itemValue="#{banco}" converter="genericConverter" forceSelection="true" scrollHeight="200">
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.listarAgencias}" update="agenciaAutoComplete" process="@this"/>
                    <p:column style="width: 10%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banco.codigoBanco}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{banco.nomeBanco}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:autoComplete>
            </p:column>          
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column style="text-align: center">
                <h:outputText value="Agência: " style="vertical-align: middle" />
            </p:column>                                                           
            <p:column>
                <p:autoComplete size="50" id="agenciaAutoComplete" value="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.bean.agencia}" completeMethod="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.pesquisaAgencia}"
                                var="agencia" itemLabel="#{agencia.nomeAgencia}" itemValue="#{agencia}" converter="genericConverter" forceSelection="true" scrollHeight="200">
                    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"/>
                    <p:column style="width: 10%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{agencia.codigoAgencia}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{agencia.nomeAgencia}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:autoComplete>
            </p:column>                                                           
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column style="text-align: right">
                <h:outputLabel value="*Data Pagamento:  " />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:panelGroup>

                    <p:calendar id="dataInicial" showOn="button" size="16"
                                readOnlyInputText="true"
                                navigator="true"
                                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  locale="pt_BR" timeZone="GMT-3"
                                value="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.bean.dataInicial}" />

                    <h:outputLabel value=" a  " />

                    <p:calendar id="dataFinal" showOn="button" size="16"
                                readOnlyInputText="true"
                                navigator="true"
                                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  locale="pt_BR" timeZone="GMT-3"
                                value="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.bean.dataFinal}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="text-align: center">
                <h:outputLabel value="Autenticação:  " />
            </p:column>
            <p:column >
                <p:inputText value="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.bean.txtAutenticacaoPesq}" size="40" maxlength="40" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="text-align: center">
                <h:outputLabel value="Valor:  " />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText style="text-align: left" id="valorPagamento" value="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.bean.txtValorPagamentoPesq}" onkeydown="mascara(this, valor);"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</div>
<p:spacer width="10px" />
<div align="center">
    <p:toolbarGroup align="left"
                    style="text-align: left;">                                       

        <p:commandButton style="width: 100px;" 
                            value="Limpar"
                            action="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.limpaCamposPesquisaPag}"
                            update="painelCamposPesquisaPag" />                                                    
        <p:spacer width="30px" /> 

        <p:commandButton style="width: 100px;"                                                
                            value="Pesquisar"
                            action="#{criticaIncorparacaoPagamento.buscarPagamentos}"                                                            
                            update=":frmCritica:tabConsultas:dlgPagamentos"
                            oncomplete="dlgPagamentos.show();" process="@form" />


    </p:toolbarGroup>
</div>

</p:panel>
<!--                            </p:fieldset>-->
</p:tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando é solicitado um *dialog* no Primefaces versões superiores a 4, a chamada do *dialog* é feita de forma diferente da que você esta usando, acredito que o seu problema seja esse.

Troque esse comando:

```
oncomplete="dlgPagamentos.show();"
```

Por esse:

```
oncomplete="PF('dlgPagamentos').show();"
```

Espero que isso resolva seu problema.

Comment: Fiz teste usando essa chamada na versão superior só que não deu certo.

Comment: RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 context.execute("dlgPagamentos.show();");

Comment: Dentro do meu metodo na controladora faço essa chamada ao executar o método de pesquisa no botão.

Comment: Olá Emerson, coloca o código completo, pois esta faltando o início do dialog, outra coisa, declara o dialog após seu código de chamada, uma vez estava tendo problema com o dialog do primefaces e não sei porque, mas depois que declarei ele no final do código ele funcionou.

Comment: Olá Edjane, resolvei o problema, a questão que a minha daliog estava dentro do meu código de chamada dentro de uma tab. Percebi que ela é um compomente externo tem que ser chamado fora. Obrigado pela diga valeu.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu Emerson!